# Jenkins Pipeline : How to poll specific branch in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on Jenkins, where I am defining a pipeline. In the pipeline, I have a codebuild stage, which will compile project for me. It's required for that I poll SCM for a specific branch(develop). I am not able to figure out how to do that with Polling. I cannot use webhooks since our Jenkins instance is behind Company Network, not reachable via github. If connection is opened from Jenkins, then yes, github can talk.

I don't see any branch option in build trigger. Am I missing something in pipeline?

[image]

So these are the build triggers. I made a push to develop, but poll logs say nothing has been pushed. How can I poll for develop? Thank you.

In pipeline script, I also added polling mechanism, but no luck :

```
   stage('Preparation') {
            git (
              poll: true,
              branch: 'origin/develop',
              credentialsId: 'ID',
              url: 'https://github.com/company/reponame.git'
            )
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jenkinsfile should be like this

```
pipeline {

agent any

triggers {
  cron('*/30 * * * *')  <-----This will run every 30 min and will pull
}

stages {

  stage('Git Checkout') {
    steps {
      checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
      branches: [[name: "*/yourbranchname"]],   <----This branch
      doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
      submoduleCfg: [],
      userRemoteConfigs: [
        [credentialsId: "ID",
          url: "yourgitrepo url"
        ]
      ]
    ])
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I have 2 questions : 1) From the triggers, just Jenkin keep track that there has been no change, and doesn't proceed to next stage, or it just compiles it anyway. 2) In checkout, I only want to check if there is any change on develop, and then trigger codebuild. I have the codebuild script already in place. Does it go as next step in git checkout? Thank you.

Comment: I made it every 2 minutes and pulled. Then just to be sure, did a push on develop as well. Nothing unfortunately.